# How to build a register live api successfully on heroku?

Tags: mongodb, heroku

How to fix this, mongo error MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.

```
const db = require('./configs/config').get(process.env.NODE_ENV);
```

my code is:

index.js

```
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect(db.DATABASE, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    console.log("database is connected");
})
```

config.js code:

```
const config = {
    production: {
        SECRET: process.env.SECRET,
        DATABASE: process.env.MONGODB_URI

    },
    default: {
        SECRET: 'mysecretkey',
        // DATABASE: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/eduInternJan'
        DATABASE: 'mongodb+srv://Sagarkumar:Sagar457@cluster0.96hmj.mongodb.net/loginapi?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
    }
}
exports.get = function get(env) {
    return config[env] || config.default
}
```

Comment: Please [edit] that into your question. Are you entirely sure that `NODE_ENV` is set to `production`?

Comment: Yes, because everything locally running perfectly. But when I am deploying on heroku it shows this error.

Comment: Environment variables vary per environment—that's the whole point. You cannot assume that they are the same on your local machine and on Heroku. They are pretty much guaranteed not to be identical. Is `MONGODB_URI` set on Heroku, as a config var?

Comment: Oh, and if those are real credentials you should invalidate them **_immediately_**. They are forever compromised, and you need to generate new ones. Editing them out of your question is _**not enough**_.

Comment: how to manage it out?

Comment: I don't understand what "manage it out" means.

Comment: sorry do you have any solution?

Comment: You haven't answered my question about `MONGODB_URI`. Is it defined as a config var on Heroku? Are you using MongoDB via [an add-on](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/#data-stores) or something you deployed manually, e.g. MongoDB Atlas?

Comment: I am using MongoDB Atlas

Comment: Yes I have set MONGODB_URI on Heroku, as a config var